# greenplum string_agg conversion into hivesql supported

Tags: hive, hiveql, greenplum

We are migrating greenplum sql query to hivesql and please find below statement available, string_agg. how do we migrate, kindly help us. below sample greenplum code needed for migration hive.

> select string_agg(Display_String, ';' order by data_day )

```
select string_agg(Display_String, ';' order by data_day )
from
(
select data_day, 
sum(revenue)/1000000.00 as revenue,
data_day||' '||trim(to_char(sum(revenue),'9,999,999,999')) as Display_String 
from(
select case when data_date = current_date  then 'D:'
when data_date = current_date - 1 then ' D-01:'
when data_date = current_date - 2 then ' D-02:'
when data_date = current_date - 7 then ' D-07:'
when data_date = current_date - 28 then ' D-28:'
end data_day, revenue/1000000.00 revenue
from test.testable
where data_date between current_date - 28 and current_date and hour <=(Select hour from ( select row_number() over(order by hour desc) iRowsID, hour from test.testable where data_date = current_date and  type = 'UVC')tbl1
where irowsid = 2) and type in( 'UVC')
order by 1 desc) a
group by 1)aa;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like this in hive. However you can use `collect list` and `partition by/Order by` to calculate it.

```
select concat_ws(';', max(concat_str)) 
FROM (
SELECT collect_list(Display_String) over (order by data_day ) concat_str 
FROM 
(your above SQL) s ) concat_qry)r
```

Explanation -

1. collect list concats the string and while doing it it, order by orders data on day column.
2. Outermost MAX() will pickup max data for the concatenated string.

Pls note this is a very slow operation. Test performance as well before implementing it.

Here is a sample SQL and result to help you.

```
select
  id, concat_ws(';', max(concat_str)) 
from
  ( select
      s.id, collect_list(s.c) over (partition by s.id  order by s.c  ) concat_str 
    from
      ( select 1 id,'ax' c union 
      select 1,'b' 
      union select 2,'f' 
      union select 2,'g' 
      union all select 1,'b' 
      union all select 1,'b'  )s
  )  gs  
group by  id
```

[image]

Comment: i followed but query not supporting sub query in hive

Comment: select concat_ws(';', max(concat_str)) 
FROM (
SELECT collect_list(Display_String) over (order by data_day ) concat_str 
FROM

Comment: (select data_day, sum(revenue)/1000000.00 as revenue,data_day||' '||trim(regexp_replace(sum(revenue), '(?!^)(\\d\\d\\d(?=(\\d\\d\\d)*\\b))', ',$1')) as Display_String 
from(select case when data_date = current_date  then 'D:' when data_date = date_sub(current_date,1) then ' D-01:'
when data_date = date_sub(current_date,2) then ' D-02:'
when data_date = date_sub(current_date,7) then ' D-07:'
when data_date = date_sub(current_date,28) then ' D-28:'
 end data_day, revenue/1000000.00 revenue
from test.tablename

Comment: where data_date between date_sub(current_date,28) and current_date and 
hour <=(Select hour from ( select row_number() over(order by hour desc) iRowsID, 
hour from test.tablename where data_date = current_date and  type = 'UVC')tbl1
where irowsid = 2) and type in( 'UVC')
order by 1 desc) a
group by 1) aa ) concat_qry

Comment: trim(to_char(sum(revenue),'9,999,999,999')) as Display_String --- changed to -->trim(regexp_replace(sum(revenue), '(?!^)(\\d\\d\\d(?=(\\d\\d\\d)*\\b))', ',$1'))

Comment: can you pls edit your qn and update latest SQL and the exact error message?